# Solution for "UntypedActor" deprecated in Akka (Java) Tutorial

Tags: java, static, akka

### Original Code

Akka tutorial has the following code: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.2/intro/getting-started-first-java.html

```
public void calculate (final int nrOfWorkers, final int nrOfElements, final int nrOfMessages){
    ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("PiSystem");
    final ActorRef listener = system.actorOf(Props.create(Listener.class), "listener");
    ActorRef master = system.actorOf(new Props(new UntypedActorFactory() {
            public UntypedActor create() {
                return new Master(nrOfWorkers, nrOfMessages, nrOfElements, listener);
            }
    }), "master");
    master.tell(new Calculate(), ActorRef.noSender());
}
```

in which, `UntypedActorFactory` is deprecated.

### My Mod

So I tried to use `Props.create` such as

```
ActorRef master = system.actorOf( Props.create(
            new Creator<Master>(){
                public Master create(){
                    return new Master(nrOfWorkers, nrOfMessages, nrOfElements, listener);
            }
    }), "master");
```

And there is Exception saying

> cannot use non-static local Creator to create actors; make it static
>   or top-level

so I start to write a static class, which has parameters needed to be passed.

```
static class LocalCreator implements Creator<Master>{
    public Master create(){
        return new Master(nrOfWorkers, nrOfMessages, nrOfElements, listener);
    }
}
```

### Question

How to pass the parameters nrOfWorkers and etc. into the `create()` function elegantly?

Comment: You need to read up on [nested classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html).  Btw, there are zillions of versions of this question that have already been asked on SO.

Comment: @Adnrew, then you lose the parameters to be used in create.  Are you familiar with Akka?  The deprecated UntypedActor allows instance of none static class.  But new one doesnot.  Maybe there is aversion of class which allows non-static class.  That's wy this Akka question is posted.

Comment: I've created an updated tutorial using 2.3.11 version for java. Try it out: [https://github.com/Shaulian/Actors-Pi-Calc-using-2.3.11-akka-java-version](https://github.com/Shaulian/Actors-Pi-Calc-using-2.3.11-akka-java-version).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you read the Akka docs (Java flavor), it lists two ways you can construct an actor that has constructor params.  The first is like so (using your example classes):

```
ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("PiSystem");
final ActorRef listener = system.actorOf(Props.create(Listener.class), "listener");
ActorRef master = system.actorOf(Props.create(Master.class, nrOfWorkers, nrOfMessages, nrOfElements, listener), "master");
master.tell(new Calculate(), ActorRef.noSender());
```

Or if you don't want to go that route, you can use a `Creator` like so:

```
public class MasterCreator implements Creator<Master>{
  private int nrOfWorkers, nrOfMessages, nrOfElements;
  private ActorRef listener;
  public MasterCreator(int nrOfWorkers, int nrOfMessages, int nrOfElements, ActorRef listener){
    this.listener = listener;
    this.nrOfElements = nrOfElements;
    this.nrOfMessages = nrOfMessages;
    this.nrOfWorkers = nrOfWorkers;
  }

  public Master create(){
    return new Master(nrOfWorkers, nrOfMessages, nrOfElements, listener);
  }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
  ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("PiSystem");
  final ActorRef listener = system.actorOf(Props.create(Listener.class), "listener");
  ActorRef master = system.actorOf(Props.create(new MasterCreator(nrOfWorkers, nrOfMessages, nrOfElements, listener)), "master");
  master.tell(new Calculate(), ActorRef.noSender());
```

Comment: Thanks, your first solution definitely works.  But your second looks like exactly mine failed codes.  It gives me exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot use non-static local Creator to create actors; make it static or top-level

Comment: @Splash, good catch.  I updated my solution to not include the anonymous class approach as that seems to not be allowed.